# command-t not finding files

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I've recently installed `command-t` plugin on vim and started playing with it.

But now I feel that it fails finding some files.

For example: I have and `inc` folder and none of it's contents is listed when I hit `<leader> t` (and type inc or any filename inside that folder). Other files, in the main folder, aren't listed too.

I've tried flushing using `CommandTFlush` but no success.

Is there anything missing in my configuration? What can I try to get it working?

Edit: If I go inside `inc` folder (using `:cd`) the files are listed. Then, if I return to the parent folder (`:cd ..`), the same files are not listed any more.

Comment: You must show us your configuration if you want us to tell you if there's anything wrong with it.

Comment: I have nothing related to `command-t` into my `.vimrc` file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've set `let g:CommandTMaxFiles=50000` in `.vimrc` and now it is working.

Looks like there was a problem with the max indexed file limit.

Comment: I ran into this problem too, and your tip fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Use :pwd to check which is your current working directory. Command-T only works in the current directory.
My guess is that you started vim in a subdirectory of the main tree, and that's why you aren't seeing everything.

Comment: I've checked that more than once, but no luck :( 
I've also `:cd` from vim into the project directory but the result is the same.